# How to find nodes by role with knife-solo and chef-solo-search, i.e. search(:node, "role:some_role")?

Tags: chef-infra, chef-solo, knife-solo

I'm trying to set up a couple of servers using knife-solo, and I need to use a basic search in a recipe so I can know which servers are implementing a particular role.  This seems like the most basic purpose for using search.

I am using chef-solo-search, however I'm not able to find nodes by role as (it seems to be) described in the docs; I am totally stumped.  I can hack a solution, but it seems like I am doing something wrong. I built a simplified example to demonstrate my problem.

### This does not work...

I created a dummy role **roles/test_role.json**

```json
{
   "name": "test_role",
   "default_attributes": {},
   "json_class": "Chef::Role",
   "run_list": [],
   "description": "",
   "override_attributes": {}
}
```

My basic recipe to test searching for nodes with "test_role" role:
**site-cookbooks/nodesearch/recipes/default.rb**

```ruby
# required for search with knife-solo
include_recipe "chef-solo-search"

# this is now the test code for chef-solo-search shows to search for nodes that implement a role.
# see https://github.com/edelight/chef-solo-search/blob/master/tests/test_search.rb ~ line 208
nodes = search(:node, "role:test_role")

# This creates a line for each node found in the search...
search_content = nodes.map {|node| "id: #{node['id']}  run_list: #{node['run_list']}\n"}.join

# And writes it to a file
file "/var/test_role_nodes.txt" do
  content search_content
  action :create
end
```

And I have created two nodes:

**nodes/node1.json**

```json
{
  "id": "node1",
  "run_list": ["recipe[nodesearch]"]
}
```

**nodes/node2.json**

```json
{
  "id": "node2",
  "run_list": ["role[test_role]"]
}
```

When I "cook" node1 (which runs the nodesearch recipe,) I am expecting the **search(:node, "role:test_role")** search to find node2, but it returns nothing.  I have tried moving the node definitions to the data_bags directory
because the docs (in places) seem to imply this is necessary, and I have tried all sorts of
shenanigans with solo.rb settings, etc.  I believe I have set up chef-solo-search per the documented instructions, and I don't get any errors to indicate otherwise.  Out of ideas.

### But this works...

The only thing I have done that *does* work is this:  rewriting the search recipe from:

```ruby
nodes = search(:node, "role:test_role")
```

to this:

```ruby
nodes = search(:node, "run_list:*role\\[test_role\\]*")
```

The second form actually gets me the desired results.  It's an acceptable workaround, but it seems like a bit of a hack, and it leaves me wondering...
either I must be doing something awfully wrong, or all the docs for knife-solo and chef-solo-search are
wrong (which seems quite unlikely!)

Can anyone help explain why I can't get any search results using **search(:node, "role:test_role")**  ??

(We've explicitly chosen *not* to use a chef server solution for a number of carefully-considered reasons.)

Answer (score 0):

Chef Solo does not support search:

> chef-solo is an open source version of the chef-client that allows using cookbooks with nodes without requiring access to a server. chef-solo runs locally and requires that a cookbook (and any of its dependencies) be on the same physical disk as the node. chef-solo is a limited-functionality version of the chef-client and does not support the following:
>
> - Node data storage
> - **Search indexes** <-
> - Centralized distribution of cookbooks
> - A centralized API that interacts with and integrates infrastructure components
> - Authentication or authorization
> - Persistent attributes

Source: http://docs.opscode.com/chef_solo.html

Comment: Yes, that's why I am also using chef-solo-search...
https://github.com/edelight/chef-solo-search

I may be using it incorrectly, but it does work for a variety of searches, just not working as expected for node/role searches.

Comment: I don't think chef-solo-search supports advanced use cases like search for roles or run_lists on nodes.

Comment: Wondering if there is some difficulty in terminology.  For example, is  this: search(:node, "role:test_role") an indexed search while this search(:node, "run_list:*role\\[test_role\\]*") is not?  Or am I perhaps getting lost in the node vrs data_bag/node/ mismatches between knife-solo and chef-solo-search?

Comment: sethvargo, thanks, I was supposing it did based on the test code I referenced: https://github.com/edelight/chef-solo-search/blob/master/tests/test_search.rb ~ line 208

But simply not being supported might be the simplest explanation why I can't get it to work  ;-)

Answer (score 0):

It does not work because you need to specify this in the node's json file for chef-solo-search to consider it to be a real node object instead of a normal `Hash`:

```
"json_class": "Chef::Node"
```

It will be searchable by roles after this. So basically your example `node2` should look like this:

```
{
  "id": "node2",
  "run_list": ["role[test_role]"]
  "json_class": "Chef::Node"
}
```

I've noticed this by examining the tests for chef-solo-search which you linked in the last comment of the first answer. The role search test are only run on `alpha` and `beta` nodes and not on `without_json_class` node, and I found the difference, which is that the latter one class assert to a `Hash` [here](https://github.com/edelight/chef-solo-search/blob/master/tests/test_search.rb#L198) instead of a `Chef::Node`.

Comment: Current versions won't work this way, with my rig, at least.  Adding the ```"json_class": "Chef::Node"``` element to the node results in somehow having the "id" value set to nil, resulting in an error accessing the databag_item (i.e. the node.)